# Check for one more condition with this code javascript

Tags: javascript, html

**This is my code**

```
//Remove disabled class from the next step button
  var element = document.getElementById('stepbirth');
  element.classList.toggle("disabled", parseJson.some(function (resp) {
    return !resp.code;
  }));
```

Which is working fine, it check the response from the php script on each element and toggle the disabled class from the button.

My question is this, How can i check one or more condition with this code..
Like i also have input type radio in the same form, how can i combine this together to check while input radio is checked on each class and response code is 1 then remove disabled class else do not remove disabled class.

I hope you understand guys my question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to return true or false by checking if all the conditions are met. Something like this:

```
//Remove disabled class from the next step button
var element = document.getElementById('stepbirth');
element.classList.toggle("disabled", parseJson.some(function (resp) {
return (resp.firstcondition && resp.secondcondition && resp.thirdcondition);
}));
```